# Is it possible to see passwords that Google Chrome has saved to my account from my Android phone or a secure website?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

There's an option in Chrome for me to turn on automatic password generation for when I'm creating a new online account. I'd love to use this feature but one hurdle stands in my way. If I'm on a different computer where I'm not going to sign into Chrome for whatever reason, how can I pull up that generated password to sign in?

I know that if I'm signed into Chrome and syncing everything I can go into settings and view a list of domains and the accounts that Chrome will auto fill but that's outside the scope of the scenario. How can I view that list when I'm not at my desktop or laptop? Can I find a list like that in Chrome on my Android phone or tablet? Is there another app or a website from Google I don't know about that will do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. you can access all your passwords saved in Chrome in your account at [Google Password](https://passwords.google.com/).

Comment: It probably works, but I have a sync password so I'm told I can't view my passwords on that site. So close!

Comment: You can delete your sync passphrase. check out  [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1181035?p=settings_encryption&rd=1).

Comment: I'm looking to add security to my account. I'd rather not sacrifice my passphrase so my passwords are obtainable. One step forward, two steps back. That's my preference.

Comment: I don't think any one can access your passwords stored in google account unless he have access to your google account or physical access to your signed in chrome. so it will be better idea to do that, for which according to google you should use [2 step verification](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/). Sync passphrase doesn't seems something u can rely on (in terms of security).

Answer (score 0):

You can access the list from *Chrome for Android*, as long as you're signed in to the browser.

**Open *Chrome --> Settings --> Save Passwords***

Then you'll see the list of websites that Chrome saved the passwords for.

---

As [peeyush113](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/27226/peeyush113) suggested, there's the [passwords page](https://passwords.google.com/), but as you noticed, it works only when you don't have a sync phrase turned on.